# Adding gms:play-services:11.0.0 in build.gradle gives build error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, fusedlocationproviderapi

I'm trying to use fuse location api. For that I've added this line `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.0'` in build.gradle. Without it, the app works fine.

But after adding this line gives the following error:

```
E:\Android\FuseGPSTest\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\25.2.0\res\values-v24\values-v24.xml
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    E:\backup\android studio\sdk\build-tools\24.0.1\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I E:\backup\android studio\sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar -M E:\Android\FuseGPSTest\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S E:\Android\FuseGPSTest\app\build\intermediates\res\debug -A E:\Android\FuseGPSTest\app\build\intermediates\assets\debug -m -J E:\Android\FuseGPSTest\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F E:\Android\FuseGPSTest\app\build\intermediates\res\resources-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.capitaleyenepal.fusegpstest.fusegpstest -0 apk --output-text-symbols E:\Android\FuseGPSTest\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug
Error Code:
    1
Output:
    E:\Android\FuseGPSTest\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v24\values.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
    E:\Android\FuseGPSTest\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v24\values.xml:6: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.capitaleyenepal.fusegpstest.fusegpstest"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.0'
}
```

P.S. I've installed the latest google play services and google repository

sdk manager img

[image]

Comment: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.1'`  use latest

Answer (score 0):

this version works well for me. I'll post you my entire gradle configuration, maybe it is helpful for someone

*build.gradle*

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

*app/build.gradle*

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.0"
    ...    
}
```

*gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties*

```
...
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

Hope it helps :-)